# How to load data from db with ajax?

Tags: commerce, ajax

I am new to ajax so my question might be a basic one, but I have not found an answer anywhere so I ask here.

I am building eshop website on D7 with Commerce. On page where products are displayed I have 2 custom php scripts included - one that echoes menu(filter) and one that echoes products. The menu is implemented as a filter, users can select multiple checkboxes to display multiple categories of products. These categories are passed in URL, for example /eshop?filter=category1+category2. There are about 20 products in each category, but because user can select a lot of categories, there can be quite a lot of products to fetch from db and the page load is slow. So I would like to ajaxify this process so the behavior is like this: display whole page, including menu. Display loading gif for each category while it is fetched from the database. When data are ready, display the category(replace loading gif) and continue with the next category, until all categories are displayed.

```
function loadCategory(filter){

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById(filter).innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
           
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","my_php_file.php?filter="+filter,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

I am calling the above function(taken from w3schools) on jQuery(document).ready() event multiple times for each category(filter) and it works fine. The problem is that in my_php_file.php I need to have access to drupal functions - not only db_query(), but also some commerce functions since I am building custom add to cart forms. I have tried bootstraping drupal as hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5014244/drupal-how-to-access-to-drupals-apis-with-a-standalone-php-script), but it does not work as drupal shows site telling me that drupal is already installed.

How do I achieve this? Or am I taking wrong approach? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi. Seems you are avoiding Drupal AJAX Framework, so how is it a Drupal question?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your list is implemented with views (if not you can easily do this), to load a view via Ajax use the following code; I supposed your view's name is `VIEW_NAME` and it's display machine name is `block_0` and there is a contextual filter to get `filter`

```
$.ajax({
    url: Drupal.settings.basePath + 'views/ajax',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: 'view_name=VIEW_NAME&view_display_id=block_0&view_args='+filter,
    success: function(response) {
        var output = response[1].data;
        $("#filter").html(output);
    },
   error: function(data) {
        alert('An error occured!');
    }
});
```

The Ajax call in Drupal framework is different to the one you usually see on non-Drupal websites.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. Unfortunately no, it is not loaded with views. I am quite new to drupal too and it was easier for me to do it without it(a lot of custom stuff). Is there a way to do it without views?

Comment: Then what is it?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that. It is a standard php script to load data from database. It is included in the content block(which has php code format thanks to php filter module).

Comment: How did you store the content? via nodes?

Comment: I have created content type and the eshop page( /eshop) is the only page of that type. In the content block of this page the php file is included. Sorry again for being inaccurate.

Comment: You are completely going wrong! There is a content type and it has a few contents (nodes) To list it's content use VIews module and output the view in a block. It is not that much difficult to learn.

Comment: Well, thank you for your effort. I might try it, but not now, since I have this already finished(without ajax).
So there really isn´t a way to call drupal api functions in php script called by ajax?

Comment: Im not sure you should try it. Call a template file